# How can I combine similar dimension values in Tableau by REGEX or keyword?

Tags: tableau-api

In DimensionOne below are a list of values with corresponding metric values. I want to combine the dimension values by certain "keywords" and have the metrics aggregate (in this case sum their values). I also want to be able to name these aggregations anything I want. You'll see some of the "keywords" also belong to multiple values making it trickier. Example of what I'm looking for below...

Raw Data

```
╒═══════════════════════╤═══════════════════════╤═══════════════════════╤═══════════════════════╕
│                       │ DimensionTwo          │ DimensionTwo          │ Grand Total           │
╞═══════════════════════╪═══════════╤═══════════╪═══════════╤═══════════╪═══════════╤═══════════╡
│ DimensionOne          │ MetricOne │ MetricTwo │ MetricOne │ MetricTwo │ MetricOne │ MetricTwo │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 1 Used 4008 Cante Mat │ 450       │ 4         │ 693       │ 3         │ 1143      │ 7         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 1G3939903K393         │ 403       │ 9         │           │           │ 403       │ 9         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 10349-3339LO          │           │           │ 506       │ 1         │ 506       │ 1         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 20221 New Orange R    │ 110       │ 19        │ 4950      │ 2         │ 5060      │ 21        │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ /New-5050-Freq        │ 103       │ 3         │           │           │ 103       │ 3         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ /Used-6070-Ref        │           │           │ 56        │ 8         │ 56        │ 8         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 99 Hon 2D             │ 500       │ 1         │           │           │ 500       │ 1         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ Z444Z Hyn 4F          │ 32        │ 2         │           │           │ 32        │ 2         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ /                     │ 12003     │ 55        │ 3         │ 1         │ 12006     │ 56        │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ Hon Deal Clo Bi       │ 40        │ 4         │           │           │ 40        │ 4         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 2020 fGKgjod          │ 494       │ 3         │ 33        │ 1         │ 527       │ 4         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ Used 89393Fe3         │ 87        │ 2         │           │           │ 87        │ 2         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 28 Hon 3D             │           │           │ 10        │ 1         │ 10        │ 1         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 678 Hyn 4F            │           │           │ 12        │ 2         │ 12        │ 2         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ Hyn Deal Zon Ti       │           │           │ 393       │ 9         │ 393       │ 9         │
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 2020 Hyn 1            │           │           │ 80        │ 2         │ 80        │ 2         │
╘═══════════════════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╛
```

Aggregated Data

```
╔══════════════╤═══════════════════════╤═══════════════════════╤═══════════════════════╗
║              │ DimensionTwo          │ DimensionTwo          │ Grand Total           ║
╠══════════════╪═══════════╤═══════════╪═══════════╤═══════════╪═══════════╤═══════════╣
║ DimnesionOne │ MetricOne │ MetricTwo │ MetricOne │ MetricTwo │ MetricOne │ MetricTwo ║
╟──────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Used         │ 537       │ 6         │ 749       │ 11        │ 1286      │ 17        ║
╟──────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ New          │ 213       │ 22        │ 4950      │ 2         │ 5163      │ 24        ║
╟──────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Deal         │ 40        │ 4         │ 393       │ 9         │ 433       │ 13        ║
╟──────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Home         │ 12003     │ 55        │ 3         │ 1         │ 12006     │ 56        ║
╟──────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Hon          │ 500       │ 1         │ 10        │ 1         │ 510       │ 2         ║
╟──────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Hyn          │ 32        │ 2         │ 12        │ 2         │ 44        │ 4         ║
╟──────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ 2020         │ 494       │ 3         │ 80        │ 2         │ 574       │ 5         ║
╟──────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Other        │ 403       │ 9         │ 506       │ 1         │ 909       │ 10        ║
╚══════════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╝
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This aggregation can be done by creating a new measure with a conditional calculation {which can be given any name you choose} using 'contains', as follows:

```
IF CONTAINS([DimensionOne],'deal') THEN 'deal'
ELSEIF  CONTAINS([DimensionOne],'new') THEN 'new'
ELSEIF  CONTAINS([DimensionOne],'used') THEN 'used'
END
```

Note that the earlier calculation lines take precedence. Therefore, if there is an item which includes 'deal' and 'used', it will be classified as 'deal'.

Any of the measures can then be aggregated against the new dimension selecting the new dimension and then dragging the required measure(s) to the rows or columns shelf, or the marks card.

Comment: Worth wrapping in UPPER to account for case sensitivity - i.e. CONTAINS(UPPER([DimensionOne]),'DEAL') THEN 'deal'

Comment: @reusen Thank you so much for your help! Several questions...                                           
1.) Is there a way to put 'OR' or '|' within a contains field somehow? For example if one of the rows said 'Used' and another said 'Pre-Owned' and I want them to both be aggregated under 'Used' is that possible?                                                                     2.) For everything that doesn't fall under a category how do I change it from saying 'null' to 'Other'.

Comment: You are most welcome. To address your questions, 1. you can use 'OR' and 2. You just add a final 'ELSE' line to catch everything not classified elsewhere., like this `IF CONTAINS([Dimension One],'deal') THEN 'deal'
ELSEIF  CONTAINS([Dimension One],'new') THEN 'new'
ELSEIF  CONTAINS([Dimension One],'used') or CONTAINS([Dimension One],'pre-owned') THEN 'used'
ELSE 'Unclassified'
END`

Comment: @reusen - Excellent! Thank you again! Now that I have my dimension values aggregated is there a way to change my calculated fields to reflect the new measure values associated with the dimensions? For example the aggregation summed MeasureOne and Two how I wanted but it also summed my calculated fields I created as well. How do I get my calculated fields to look at the new summed values like they would the original values? Not sure if that makes sense. Basically I would like to divide the new values of of MeasureOne and MeasureTwo (MeasureTwo/MeasureOne) instead of summing it independently.